# "tunnel mode ipsec ipv4" seems to be missing from my CISCO router

Tags: vpn, cisco, ipsec, ios, tunnel

I'm trying to set up a LAN-to-LAN IPsec tunnel and at one endpoint I have an old CISCO 871W running IOS 12.3(8)YI2. The command "tunnel mode ipsec ipv4" doesn't work:

```
router#configure terminal 
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
router(config)#interface tunnel 1
router(config-if)#tunnel mode ipsec ipv4
                                   ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.

router(config-if)#tunnel mode ?
  aurp    AURP TunnelTalk AppleTalk encapsulation
  cayman  Cayman TunnelTalk AppleTalk encapsulation
  dvmrp   DVMRP multicast tunnel
  eon     EON compatible CLNS tunnel
  gre     generic route encapsulation protocol
  ipip    IP over IP encapsulation
  iptalk  Apple IPTalk encapsulation
  nos     IP over IP encapsulation (KA9Q/NOS compatible)
```

Any ideas why? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Cisco IOS Interface and Hardware Component Command Reference](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/interface/command/ir-cr-book/ir-t2.html#wp4269279348)  tells us that this command was introduced in 12.3(14)T which is quite old, but unfortunately your IOS version is just a tiny bit older than that.

Edit: unless you can upgrade the router, depending on your use case (and what the other router supports), you can instead use:

- a [regular (crypto map based) L2L tunnel](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/routers/1700-series-modular-access-routers/71462-rtr-l2l-ipsec-split.html)
- a 'classic' [GRE/IPsec tunnel](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/solutions/Enterprise/WAN_and_MAN/P2P_GRE_IPSec/P2P_GRE/2_p2pGRE_Phase2.html)  (if you need to have a Tunnel interface for e.g. a routing protocol), where IPsec is done using a crypto-map
- a [GRE/IPsec tunnel with Tunnel Protection](https://learningnetwork.cisco.com/docs/DOC-2457).